# Looking for Help to fix Angular 8 to 9 Upgrade issue - Getting error in tab.js file

Tags: angular, angular-material2

[Once try to access the app in browser its keep on loading and throwing 500 -1000 errors in tabs.js file. (this._tabList.nativeElement is coming as empty). We are using Mat-tab in our project. Looks like material design is causing this issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zno1h.png)

Answer (score 0):

looks like your anguler/material is still at 7. Try to upgrade it to 9.

https://update.angular.io/?v=7.2-9.0

click "I use material" option then you'll get a list of things you need to do to upgrade it.